# Magento module's block code is working in product details page but not working in category and list page?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, layout, product-list, category

In magento I am writing one module. In my module lets say I have `mymodule.xml` where I want to insert my own block after this block

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="test/test" name="test" as="other" template="test/test.phtml" >
        <block type="test/test" name="test_info" as="test_info" template="test/testinfo.phtml" />
      </block>
    </reference>
  </catalog_product_view>
```

This one is working fine in product details view page but when I am trying to show the same block  in product category view and list view its not working at all.
  The product list category is like this where I am inserting my code from `mymodule.xml`

```
    <catalog_product_list>
    <reference name="product.info">
       <block type="test/test" name="test" as="other" template="test/test.phtml" >
        <block type="test/test" name="test_info" as="test_info" template="test/testinfo.phtml" />
      </block>
    </reference>
  </catalog_product_list>
```

When I am going to check the changes in list view I can't see any changes (after clearing cache). So can someone kindly tell me how to solve this issue. Any help and suggestions wll be really appreciable. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the layout handle `catalog_product_list` doesn't exist. At least, **not unless you created it**. But by default that handle is non-existent.

What it *sounds like you're looking for* is to display it on the category pages. In that case, you're in a little bit of bad luck; there is no `product.info` block on these pages. You can instead create your block as such:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list">
       <block type="test/test" name="test" as="other" template="test/test.phtml" >
        <block type="test/test" name="test_info" as="test_info" template="test/testinfo.phtml" />
      </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

If you're not using layered navigation, change that to `catalog_category_default`.

Then, in your `catalog/product/list.phtml` you will want to add the following echo statement inside of the product listing div:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('test_info);
```

Comment: still its not showing....

Comment: still its not working